# Is it possible to customize the GPG validity using a custom git log format?

Tags: git, git-log

I have specified a git alias which shows GPG signature validity in a commit log.

```
[alias]
    l = log --graph --decorate --pretty=format:'%C(auto)%G? %H %d%n%an <%ae> [%ai]%n%n  %s%n%Creset'
```

A full reference of the format can be found [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats).

I’m using `%G?` to show the GPG signature validity of each commit. This shows `G` for a good signature, `B` for a bad signature, etc.

Is it possible to customize the characters used to indicate the signature validity? E.g. `%Cgreen✔%C(auto)` for good, `%Cgreen✖%C(auto)` for bad, etc.? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it. It seems `signature_check.result` in [pretty.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ccdcbd54c4475c2238b310f7113ab3075b5abc9c/pretty.c#L1237) is checked against a fixed list of characters and then used literally.